ecommerce flutter App Error Identity matrix error
I need to solve this issue
Identity matrix error when i login
I/ImeTracker( 9415): com.activeitzone.activeecommerceflutterapp:c567ec2a: onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT_SHOW_SOFT_INPUT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT D/InputMethodManager( 9415): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{bee77fe VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2154 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
this the error in console
can't solve it please help me

Add the relevent code, so that we can understand the prblm in your code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
